# deadlock occuring in mutex code

Tags: c, mutex, deadlock

I have developed a user level thread library. In the code, deadlock occurs sometimes, but i am unable to figure out why it is happening. Here is the code for mutex lock and unlock functions:

```
int gtthread_mutex_lock(gtthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
   if(!mutex) //checks if mutex is null
       return -1;
   while(mutex->available==1); //spin locks if mutex is already locked by someone else
   __sync_val_compare_and_swap(&mutex->available,0,1); //atomic function to swap value 0 with 1 
   mutex->owner=node->th;
   return 0;
}

int gtthread_mutex_unlock(gtthread_mutex_t *mutex)
{
    if(!mutex) return -1;

    if(mutex->available)
    {
        mutex->available=0;
        mutex->owner=NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is homework: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2005/cs6210_fall/Project1writeup.html

Comment: Yes, it is a project . I am not asking for code. I am just asking for a situation in which the mutex wont work. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another thread might obtain the lock between your `while` test and the swap.

You'd have to check the return of `__sync_val_compare_and_swap` and reiterate if it didn't succeed.

Also your code for keeping track of the owner will not work, because in your unlock you may delete the information that some other thread has written.

Better you just have one field (handled with atomic operations) which holds the info on the owner and that is 0 if there is none.